# How to escape compress in apache ftl

Tags: freemarker

In apache ftl IMHO there are no way to escape the compress directive. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

I can't close and reopen the compress directive in between to escape compress.

```
<#compress>
Normal text
<#nocompress>
Hello

How are you?
</#nocompress>
</#compress>
```